# Como posso mostrar uma imagem que está no banco usando jsp?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlet

Bom, é o seguinte. Estou usando JSP, SERVLET e MySQL para inserir imagens no meu projeto, acontece que eu apenas guardo o caminho da imagem no banco, e depois chamo esse caminho para mostrar a imagem. Daí acontece o problema:

```
<%
        ArrayList<Fotos> lista = new ArrayList<Fotos>();
        try {
            Fotos f = new Fotos();
            lista = f.listar();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.print("Erro:" + e);
        }

        for (Fotos fl : lista) {

    %>
    <p><%=fl.getId()%><p>
        <img src="img/<%fl.getLink()%>">
<td><a href="alterar_foto.jsp?id=<%=fl.getId()%>">alterar</a>/<a href="#" onclick="excluir('<%=fl.getLink()%>', '<%=fl.getId()%>');">excluir</a>
    <%
        }
    %>
```

O caminho da imagem no meu computador é: C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\EngatFitOriginal\web\img

só que não mostra na página de listar:

[image: É assim que o link aparece no hmtl]

Alguém sabe como fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, recomendo você salvar somente o nome do arquivo no BD e no código fazer uma concatenação do do path do projeto + resultado da consulta do BD que retornará o nome da foto.

Ex: No BD você salva foto_fit_original.jpg e no JSP você retorna o path do projeto e concatena com o resultado da consulta do banco.

O Javascript final deve processar apenas /web/img/foto.jpg ao invés de C:/Users/Gabriel/Documents/EngatFitOriginal/web/img/foto.jpg

Comment: Verdade, funcionou. Obrigado.